# "golang.org/x/time/rate" and Context

Tags: go, time, throttling, rate-limiting

What's the purpose of passing the context to Wait() function in the example below?

Let's say there is a limiter that allow 3 requests per second.

Does it mean that limiter will not be a shared resource in the sense that, for each "Process" function call, it will have it's own limiter instance and scope, is that right?
If it's not the case? How can I achieve it?

Struct

```
type MyClass struct {
    limiter *rate.Limiter
}

func NewMyClass() (*MyClass, error) {
    return &MyClass{limiter: rate.NewLimiter(rate.Limit(3), 1)}, nil
}

func (m *MyClass) Process(ctx context.Context) error {
    err := m.limiter.Wait(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    //more code
}
```

Example

```
m, _ := s3Storage.NewMyClass()
    
    ctx1 := context.TODO()
    m.Process(ctx1)
    m.Process(ctx1)
    m.Process(ctx1)

    ctx2 := context.TODO()
    m.Process(ctx2)
```

Comment: If the context is cancelled (proactively or via timeout) then Wait will return early with the context error (reason for cancelation). This is a common practice that is used when calling any potentially blocking call.

Comment: So how can I create a limiter that is not shared across multiple Process func calls, given I just instantiate MyClass once? I believed rate.Limiter could handle this under the hoods, if different contexts were passed. It seems not to be the case, right?

Comment: The context does not have anything to do with the actual rate limiting.  It just allows the wait to be cancelled (eg if it is taking too long).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you need to understand the different purposes of the `rate.Limiter` and `context.Context` types.  The `Limiter` allows you to control the rate at which concurrent processes are executed.  The `Context` allows to terminate a process or group of processes if there is no point in them continuing (eg timeout, lost connection, user-cancellation...).  These are simplifications so read the doco for more info.

To answer your questions:

> What's the purpose of passing the context to Wait() function in the example?

There is no purpose as the `TODO` context is never cancelled.

> Does it mean the limiter will not be a shared resource...?

No, it is shared.  You only have one `MyClass` instance which only has one `Limiter`.

> If not ... how can I achieve it?

There is no point in having a limiter on each Process function call, since one call will never exceed your limit of 3.

I *think* you want multiple different sets of rate-limited calls to `Process`, and so probably just need multiple instances of `MyClass`, each with it's own `Limiter`.

I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to do, but as an example a typical use of a rate limiter is to restrict the number of processes by user or by connection.  Similarly, a context may be associated with all the processes attached to a single connection, so that if the connection dies everything can be neatly cleaned up.  So a possible scenario is that you have a `Connection` type that has a `Limiter` and a `Context`.

I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

The context defines the lifetime of the call, so if the context is cancelled, then the wait call will be cancelled as well. As an example, try changing the context from `context.TODO()` to `context.WithTimeout()` with a very small timeout and observe the effect on the Wait() call. The [official docs](https://pkg.go.dev/context) do a good job of explaining the context and semantics behind `context`.